# How can i save the order of an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an `NSMutableArray` and I change the order of the contents of it. How can I save the order of it in core data without using a relation ship, or should I use `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: If you want to use core data to store multiple objects, then it has to be a relationship, so I would say that the answer to your first question is "you can't, but you should just use a relationship". You can use `NSUserDefaults` as well.  A simple search on here or Google would show many examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a second array that is a copy of the first one at the time that you want to preserve its order?  It need not be a mutable array - use `[myArray immutableCopy]`

If you don't want to copy all the items in the array for memory reasons, perhaps store the location as an NSInteger?  Have the first array contain the items, and the second array contains indexes for the first array.